# Change color of MenuItem on MouseOver 

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

I want to change the color of a MenuItem at mouseOver. I need also rounded borders, an image and a textBox. When I set the style all is ok only the mouseOverEvent is doing anything, the background doesnot change. My code is:

```
  <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="MainBorder" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Margin="0,0,1,0"  BorderBrush="AliceBlue">

                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="Info" Margin="30,10,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="menu.PNG" Margin="-100,0,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Hope anybody know what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwritting the Template, but not using the Background Color anywhere in it so the value never gets applied.

Set the Background Color in your MenuItem Template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now it works...only the MenuItem is rectangular and it only shows me the rounded border. I want to see only the rounded border to be colored. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @user599977 Set the Background of your `Border` object instead of the `Grid`

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the `Background` anywhere in your template so changing that property has no effect.