# WPF MenuItem MouseOver does not change the background color

Tags: wpf, menuitem, mahapps.metro

As shown in the snapshot below, the `style` I used in my following `XAML` successfully changed the default background and foreground color of menu items to blue and white respectively. But on mouse over, it does not change the `background color` of the `MenuItem` to light blue (instead, it keeps the default color of mouse over). What I may be missing here, and how can we fix the issue? I tried solutions to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24786479/1232087) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790774/1232087) post but still no luck.

**Snapshot of the menu**

[image]

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_File" Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}" Width="32" Height="30">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <MenuItem Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Badged.Background}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
        <MenuItem Header="_New" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**UPDATE**

I have uploaded this very basic WPF sample project [here](https://easyupload.io/gbzykr) - in case someone wants to test his/her suggestion. This file upload link will expire in 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways:

- Not use `<MenuItem Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" />` in template and use custom template.
  If you change ControlTemplate like this:

```
<mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate"
                     TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Badged.Background}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.MenuItem}" 
           TargetType="MenuItem"
           x:Key="MenuStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}"/>        
    </Style>    
    
</mah:MetroWindow.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="_File"
                  Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent4}"
                  Width="60"
                  Height="30">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuStyle}"/>
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="_New" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Template="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

You will see the background change on Mouse over

- Use default template, but customize mouse over color. Define `SelectionFill` brush in resources. If you need setup color for application use [Application ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)
  Apply `MenuStyle` to subitems `_File`

```
<mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.MenuItem.SelectionFill" Color="White" />
    
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.MenuItem}" 
           TargetType="MenuItem"
           x:Key="MenuStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}"/>        
    </Style>
</mah:MetroWindow.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="_File"
                  Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent2}"
                  Width="60"
                  Height="30">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuStyle}" />
            </MenuItem.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="_New" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

You can check MenuItem style [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.MenuItem.xaml)
Trigger `IsHighlighted` change selection style.

```
<Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
   <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.MenuItem.SelectionFill}" />
   <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.MenuItem.SelectionStroke}" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion did not work. To make sure I'm doing it right: In my xaml  (shown in my post above), I replaced `<MenuItem Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" />` with `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />`. In your second suggestion, I'm not sure exactly where I would use the default template, and then where exactly I make the changes.

Comment: I have included a link of this very basic sample project in the **UPDATE** section of my post above - in case you or someone else want to test it on their own.

Comment: Your updated suggestion works (thank you).  A minor typo: I am sure you meant to close this tag: `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}">`.